# libxml - looping through all children of a child

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, libxml2

I am new to libxml. I would like to write 1 loop to loop through all the children of a child node etc. e.g.

`<par>i want to <bold>loop <italic>through </italic> all</bold> children in this node</pa`r>

At the moment my looping code look as follows but I only get the "bold" node and not the "italic" child.

```
    if (xmlStrEqual(node->name, BAD_CAST "p")) {

    xmlNodePtr child = node->children;

        while (child != NULL) {

            child = child->next;
        }
    }
```

It is conceivable that the node structure could grow to 4-5 elements, so I need a solution which is more robust that putting while loops within while loops. Any help would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xmlTree interface you're using is heirarchical.  <par> has 3 children - the text before <bold>, <bold> itself, and the text after.  <bold> has children of its own, which includes <italic>.  The node->children list only contains the *immediate* children of a node.

There are a couple ways to get the behavior that you want.

- While processing child, you can recursively process child->children to get to <bold>'s child, which includes <italics>
- If you're looking SPECIFICALLY for that <itallic> (or for a set of specific nodes), you can use an XPath expression, such as "par//italic" to find any italic node anywhere beneath par.
  http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#XPath
- You could look at libxml2's xmlTextReader interface rather than this xmlTree.  It provides the serial "read through" of the document that you're expecting.
  http://xmlsoft.org/xmlreader.html

Each method has its own advantages/disadvantages, depending on what all you're trying to do with your application.